# How do I store data in Java without need of extra software?

Tags: java

I am currently developing a program in Java using NetBeans that manages expenses. In this program I used MySQL to store data. Now I want to ask that if I give the program to one of my friend, he would also have to install MySQL using the same password that I used. Is there a way in which he will not be required to install MySQL?

Now suppose if my friend already has MySQL, but with a different password. My program would not work in that case, and it would be hard to replace my password with his password in the code. Is there a way to make the program run on his PC?

Earlier once, I have used an Oxford dictionary program. That time I did not have Microsoft Access installed. When I installed Microsoft Access I came to know that all the words of the dictionary are stored in a Microsoft Access file. How can I do this? I.e. how can I use MySQL/Microsoft Access to store data without the need to install either of them?

Comment: look for javadb - it can be embedded

Comment: Why not make the password and the choice of JDBC data store configurable?  You can't use a program without installing it.

Comment: a portable sql server is the answer you're looking for. one of the most popular ones is [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: Another choice would be to store the data in XML files on the local machine, not very secure for an expenses system though, but at least no other software is required to write/read the data

Comment: An embedded database like derby or h2 is fine: JDBC, full SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an in-memory database like [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) if you don't require a large amount of data

But I think you should make your db connection configurable by using a properties file

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone to be able to use the database, you need to run it on a server that people can access through the internet.

However if you don't care about them using the same database and just want them to use their own, you could for example create a small file named "config.ini" or something like that and put the login information (like the password) in there.
Then just read it in your code and use the info you read to log into your database. 
That way, every new user will only have to change the config.ini file without ever having to touch the code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in my opinion would be [SQLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm) as it is light, and data can be stored locally in a desired location in a single file. [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) is more likely to be a developer tool.

This solution does not require additional software to be present on the user machine. Of course it has its limits, but as a simply storage for program dynamic data it is a good solution. It is worth mentioning that Android applications also can store their data in [LiteSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiteSQL). It is a bit different approach there, but the principle stays the same.